# terraform for_each using terneray operation fails

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to create multiple secrets in AWS secrets manager using `for_each` just in prod environment:

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "secret_cmk" {
  deletion_window_in_days = 7
  is_enabled              = true
  enable_key_rotation     = true
  policy                  = data.aws_iam_policy_document.cmk_policy.json
}

module "airflow_conn_secret" {
  source        = "./modules/..."
  for_each      = var.env == "prd" ? local.secrets : {}
  name          = each.value.secret_id
  kms_key_id    = aws_kms_key.secret_cmk.key_id
  secret_string = jsonencode(each.value)
}

locals {
   secrets = {
     secret1 = {
        "secret_id"   = ""
        "secret_type" = ""
        "host"      = var.host
        "login"     = var.user
        "password"  = var.pwd
        "info" = {
          ...
        }
    }
    ...more secrets
   }
 }
}
```

But I get `The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The given expressions are object and object, respectively.` How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What is the full, complete error message? Which line exactly it originates from?

Comment: error coming from `for_each` line. If I provide a similar local variable for both side of the ternary operation then it works. But I don't want to created the secrets in nonprod environment. So I provide an empty map which causes the issue.

Comment: Your code is correct from what you posted. There is no reason for it to fail.

Comment: I updated the question. As you can see each secret object in the locals can have an extra property `info` which causes my code to fail.

Comment: This wouldn't cause your error. The only possibility I can think of is that you have some old TF version and this was some bug before.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your goal is to declare zero instances of `module.airflow_conn_secret` if `var.env` does not equal `"prd"`.

A different way to achieve that result which doesn't require both conditional "arms" to have the same type is to instead construct a new mapping that has all of the elements filtered out in that case:

```
  for_each = {
    for k, v in local.secrets : k => v
    if var.env == "prd"
  }
```

Because the `if` clause doesn't refer to either `k` or `v`, this particular filter will either keep all or discard all of the elements of `local.secrets`, getting the effect you wanted.

If you had another situation where you only wanted to keep a subset of the elements then you could write an `if` clause that uses either `k` or `v` to make a decision based on each specific element, but that isn't needed for your use-case here.